# Checking for anomalies in a pandas dataframe row with respect to other rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has information for a collection of products and their properties. Each product is described in a single row as so:

```
df = 
   product prop1 prop2 prop3
0        A     a     b     c
1        B    aa    bb     c
2        C     a     b     c
3        D     a    bb     c
4        E    aa     b     c
5        F     a    bb    cc
6        G    aa     b     c
7        H     a     b     c
```

I am trying to find a way to investigate any specific product for key differences in its combinations of property values compared with other products. That, is I do not only want to see if each property has an uncommon value with respect to other values in that column, but use combinations of properties and values together to see if a particular combination is uncommon.

The naive approach I was thinking was to first find all the combinations of (property, value) pairs for my product of interest and then scan the dataframe to see what is an uncommon combination. However, the number of combinations for any product's (property, value) pairs is (2^N - 1) where N is the number of properties.. so this is not doable for large values of N.

For example, product D above has relatively common values for prop1, prop2, and prop3... but prop1 + prop2  ( a + bb ) is pretty uncommon, and prop1 + prop2 + prop3 is a combination unique to product D, ( a + bb + c ).

Could anyone recommend a better way to approach this problem rather than my naive approach that does not scale well? Thanks in advance, and general advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Are each of your columns numerical (continuous or integer valued), categorical, or are some columns numerical and some categorical?

Comment: It is a mix, but almost all are categorical.

Comment: You've searched for "categorical data anomaly detection"? There's several results that look promising and may be more appropriate for your data than the naive approach you mentioned, e.g. [CompreX](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/lakoglu/pubs/12-akoglu-anomaly-categoric.pdf). I haven't used it myself but there's a basic initial implementation [here](https://github.com/HamedMP/CompreX).

Comment: @ChrisHunt Thanks for the links they look very interesting. I did not search for that as I didn't know what this type of problem is referred to as, but will try doing some research on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for products who have a combination of properties that are unique, obviously you'd need to do something more complicated. I'm not entirely sure you can get away from this time complexity explosion considering you'd have to consider every combination of properties. For example, for 10 properties, there are actually 40 different combinations of 2-item pairs, and 1023 unique combinations of the properties.

However, if you want to classify as an outlier a product whose combination of *all* the properties is unique, this problem becomes trivial.

Create a hashmap/dictionary with the combinations of the properties as keys, and the count that that combination occurs as a value. For example (the following code is working but highly conceptual and would need to be optimized and tweaked for your dataframe):

```
productA = (1, "Pan", 24.99)
productB = (1, "Pan", 24.99)
productC = (1, "Pan", 24.99)
productD = (2, "Pan", 24.99)
productE = (2, "Pan", 24.99)
productF = (2, "Stove", 24.99)
productG = (1, "Stove", 78.99)

products = [productA, productB, productC, productD, productE, productF, productG]

combination_dict = dict()
for product in products:
    if product in combination_dict:
        combination_dict[product] += 1
    else:
        combination_dict[product] = 1

#Get all of the "outliers"
outliers = []
uniqueness_threshold = 2
for product in products:
    if combination_dict[product] < uniqueness_threshold:
        outliers.append(product)

print(outliers)
```

Which prints:

```
[(2, 'Stove', 24.99), (1, 'Stove', 78.99)]
```

Comment: Thanks Will, however this is not what I am interested in. Just FYI an alternative more pandorable approach for that would be df.groupby(propertyColumns).size().reset_index(name="count"), and Drop rows with count below some  threshold.